# Adicionar dados de um formulário em um array

Tags: php

Estou tentando criar uma lista de produtos em php e ao clicar em enviar queria que fosse armazenado **N** produtos no array, porem o que acontece é que cada vez que eu clico em enviar ele adiciona um novo valor e não mantem o antigo.

**formulario.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Formulario</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Produto</h1>
    <form action="#" method="POST">
        <label for="name">Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name">

        <label for="description">Description:</label>
        <textarea name="description" id="description" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>

        <label for="price">Price:</label>
        <input type="number" name="price" id="price">

        <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </form>
    <?php
        include "Product.class.php";

        if($_POST){
            $product = new Product;

            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $description = $_POST['description'];
            $price = $_POST['price'];

            $product->addProduct($name, $description, $price);

            $product->showProducts();         
        }
        ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**Product.class.php**

```
<?php

class Product 
{
    public $products;

    public function addProduct($name, $description, $price){
        return $this->products[] = [$name, $description, $price];
    }

    public function showProducts(){
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($this->products);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

Comment: O que acontece é que como você tem um único `<form>` com apenas 3 campos que enviam 3 informações: `name`, `description` e `price`, quando você realiza o envio, você só está informando dados de um único produto. Na próxima vez que a página recarregar e você tentar enviar outro produto, o objeto `$product` não irá manter o atributo que foi definido no `POST` anterior, ou seja, ele vai estar zerado. É recomendado também definir o atributo `$products` da classe como `private`, isso garante o princípio do encapsulamento.

Comment: o que preciso fazer então para as informações serem mantidas ?

Comment: Vale lembrar que http é um protocolo sem estado. Cada vez que invoca uma pagina php o seu código corre todo de novo. Se cria uma lista de produtos numa página, ela vai ser sempre criada nessa página.

Answer (score 0):

Paulo Imon já explicou o porque de não armazenar então uma solução seria armazenar esses dados em uma [sessão](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.session-start.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include "Product.class.php";

    if(empty($_SESSION["produtos"]))
        $_SESSION["produtos"] = [];

    if($_POST){
        $product = new Product;

        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $description = $_POST['description'];
        $price = $_POST['price'];

        array_push($_SESSION["produtos"], $product->addProduct($name, $description, $price));
    }

    var_dump($_SESSION["produtos"]);
    ?>
```